# Robot Framework - Using Pabot when customized Java jars are present

Tags: robotframework

Am new to RobotFrameWork.
I have created  customized keywords Using Java and created a Jar and 
I have executed the test case as follows:

### Case1:

Customized Created Jar Name : X.jar
Test Case Name                : test.txt

I have successfully executed the test case by the following ways:

Method 1(Using standalone robot framework jar):   java -cp X.jar:robotframework-2.5.3.jar org.robotframework.RobotFramework test.txt
Method 2(Using Jython)                               :   jython -P X.jar test.txt

Can any one guide me how to use Pabot in above case.

### Case2:

Customized Created Jar Name : X.jar
Test Cases Folder Name      : TestCases
Test case folder contents            : Test1.txt,Test2.txt,Test3.txt,Test4.txt,Test5.txt

If any of the test cases are not using X.jar 
I successfully executed using Pabot command as follows.

Method 1(Using pabot directory Name): pabot TestCases

But as part of requirement in all the test cases we have to use keywords Present in X.jar.In this case how to 
use Pabot to execute the test cases.

Can any one guide me in solving these issues

### I have tried pabot as follows:

command:  pabot --command java -jar robotframework-2.5.3.jar  --end-command sx;

Note:sx is the folder name containing test cases.
But am facing an error as follows:

It started execution and am getting error  as follows:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pabot/result_merger.py", line 116, in merge
    assert len(result_files) > 0
AssertionError

Answer (score 1):

robotframework-2.5.3.jar is a very very old version (released in Aug 31, 2010) and will most likely not be supported (first pabot was released in Jan 20, 2014). Please find a fresher version of Robot Framework from:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3Arobotframework

Comment: Thank you. Pabot is working fine with robotframework2.9 jar